# Keep aspect ratio of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to keep the aspect ratio of 2 `divs`. The way I did it, was I made the height equal to `20vw`, and the width is a percentage.

When I resize the window, it works as it's supposed to. The problem is when I add a margin. When I add a margin to the `divs`, the width becomes smaller, and the height stays the same, so the aspect ratio changes.

How can I keep the aspect ratio when I change the margin amount? (If this is the way it's supposed to behave, then is there a workaround?

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jykwqgpo/), and here's the code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("div").css({
            "margin": "0 20px",
                "width": "calc(100% / 2 - 40px)" //Subtract the margin
        });
    });
});
```

```css
div {
    height: 20vw;
    width: calc(100% / 2);
    float: left;
}
#first {
    background-color: yellow;
}
#second {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
<button>Add Margins</button>
```

Comment: _"trying to keep the aspect ratio of 2 divs"_ Can define "aspect ratio" ? What is expected result ?

Comment: I want the height to also resize when I change the margin

Comment: _"want the height to also resize when I change the margin "_ What should `height` be resized to ? Why would `height` change when `margin` changed ? `"margin": "0 20px"` sets vertical margin to `0px` ?

Comment: @jessica, you might want to use ``` top``` property. See this : http://codepen.io/McQuinTrix/pen/meRONE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would have an outer container that uses a property such as a percentage width or `20vw`, (viewport width) and inside of that element I would create divs that use percentages for their width and padding.

> Some examples:
>   **[Height equals width in pure CSS](http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html)**
>   **[Equal width and height](http://siebennull.com/equal_width_height.html)**
>   **[JSFiddle simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/jaggedsoftware/B8FU8/6843/)**

```css
#container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}
#dummy {
    margin-top: 75%;
}
#element {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    border: 3px dotted silver;
    padding-top:14px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="dummy"></div>
    <div id="element">
        resize to maintain aspect ratio
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO and will be deleted.